# What is main extension of this .dat file

Tags: file-format

I have some `.dat` files, for which an application on windows reads and shows some text (it's a library). I want use that text. In the application folder are some `.dat` files. some of them are `.bm` files (they are image), but some of them are something that I cannot detect what are they.

For example the start of one of them is (with Notepad++):

```
//FOS\'c8\'d3\'e3\'20\'c7\'e1\'e1\'f8\'e5\'20\'c7\'e1\'d1\'cd\'e3\'e4\'20\'c7\'e1\'d1\'cd\'ed\'e3\'fe//FOE
//FOS\'dd\'d1\'ed\'c8\'fe\'e5\'c7\'ed\'20\'da\'e3\'cf\'ed\'fe//FOE
\'ab\'cd\'de\'c7\'ed\'de\'ed\'20\'cf\'d1\'c8\'c7\'d1\'e5\'20\'d1\'e6\'c7\'c8\'d8\'20\'c2\'e3\'d1\'ed\'df\'c7\'20\'e6\'20\'c7\'d3\'d1\'c7\'c6\'ed\'e1\'bb
\'e4\'e6\'ed\'d3\'e4\'cf\'e5\'3a\'81\'e1\'20\'dd\'ed\'e4\'cf\'e1\'ed\'fe
\'e3\'ca\'d1\'cc\'e3\'3a\'e3\'cd\'e3\'cf\'20\'cd\'d3\'ed\'e4\'20\'c2\'e5\'e6\'ed\'ed\'fe
\'cf\'dd\'ca\'d1\'20\'e3\'d8\'c7\'e1\'da\'c7\'ca\'20\'d3\'ed\'c7\'d3\'ed\'20\'e6\'20\'c8\'ed\'e4\'20\'c7\'e1\'e3\'e1\'e1\'ed\'fe
```

What is the type of this `.dat` file? How can I open and read it?

Comment: That are binary files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

Comment: It might help if you post a 100% hexadecimal version of the above.

Comment: Sometimes when different applications use the same file extension for differing file formats, the files may have a "[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files)" within them that can be used to identify them. In such cases, using a utility such as [TrID](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/utilities/file/TrID.php) can help you by identifying the file based on the magic number within it. You may then be able to determine what applications can process the data in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.dat` files are probably [binary files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_files). You can edit and manipulate them with [Hex Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor).

If you already use `Notepad++` you can just try its `Hex Editor` plugin (download it by `Plugin Manager`).

Comment: Given the bytes shown in the question, it might be possible to identify what kind of data it is, using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). On Unix, one would type `file filename.dat` to get a best guess.

Comment: @Arjan I totally agree, but we are on Windows (Notepad++) and have no binary file header. Isn't a hex editor a good starting point for further actions or someone who don't know what a binary file is?

Answer (score 0):

While other answer stating that those are binary files is true, hex editor is probably not the native tool to use them.

There are plenty of programs using binary files with .dat extension, also plenty of them having different standards how they convert data to binary.

So while you really can edit them with a hex editor you probably won't be able to understand their content. The only option is to find out somehow which program has created them and open them with it.

Comment: Given the bytes shown in the question, it might be possible to identify what kind of data it is, using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). On Unix, one would type `file filename.dat` to get a best guess.